# How does a VPN Client connect to Different Servers behind the VPN Server

Tags: openvpn, synology-diskstation

I have a small (Debian) virtual machine in the cloud and a home network with a Raspberry Pi acting as the main firewall/gateway. The gateway supports external/internal mail and web services and allows SSH into it, and from there SSH onwards to other machines in my house. The cloud server currently supports two personal static (Jekyll constructed) web sites and secondary mail server. Because it has a non blocked static IP address all my house mail has to be routed through it.

My (Windows) laptop and iPhone can access mail whilst out as they use externally the name `mail.chandlerfamily.org.uk` as the name of the IMAP and SMTP mail server. Whilst in the home, my internal DNS server serves these as x.x.x.200, the address of the mail server gateway.

My laptop also has access to a web site supported on the gateway that I currently expose (but would prefer not to).

It also servers multiple web sites I am developing internally (represented here by `dev.chandlerfamily.org.uk`) with different internal addresses. This allows me to get Let's Encrypt certificates from them by supporting their protocol on port 80 and copying the supplied keys to the appropriate internal machine on my network.

The following is an ASCII diagram to represent that

```
          (www.chandlerfamily.org.uk)                           (home.chandlerfamily.org.uk) (dev.chandlerfamily.org.uk)
          (mail2.chandlerfamily.org.uk) (Secondary MX)          (mail.chandlerfamily.org.uk) (Primary MX)
       ------------------------------                           ----------------
       |    Cloud Server            |                           | ISP Router    |
       |                            |                           |               |
  443->| Nginx 2 Static Web Sites   |<-22                       -----------------
  80 ->| Certbot for Keys           |                             |(port fwd) | DMZ 
  25 ->| PostFix Mail               |<-25(1)                      V           -------------------------
       ------------------------------                           High Ports    |   |   |   |   |   |   |
                                                                (for game)    80 443  25 587 465 993  22
                                                                  |           |   |   |   |   |   |   | 
         ----------                                               V           V   V   V   V   V   V   V
         |Laptop  | 443->(home.chandlerfamily.org.uk)        (internal PC)  ----------------------------
         |        | 993 (587) (mail.chandlerfamily.org.uk)                  |   Gateway Machine        |
         ----------                              (all outgoing mail) 25(1)<-|    (x.x.x.200)           |
                                                 (via cloud server)         |  DNS and DHCP Server     |
                                                 (non blocked ip address)   |  Mail Server Certbot     |
                                                                            |  Web Site                |
                                                                            ----------------------------
                                                                            (all ports open)
                                                                            home.chandlerfamilly.org.uk, mail.chandlerfamily.org.uk
                                                                            appear as x.x.x.200
                                                                            dev.chandlerfamily.org.uk as my internal dev machine
```

This has worked well for years although I have a few suspicions that there might be some mail related holes as I sometimes see spammers mail in my sent mail folder. I'm not sure.

I recently started to better understand a Synology NAS I have had for a while (until now purely a file backup repository) and saw that it has a VPN server capability. I'm thinking I could further lock down my home by utilising that. And by the same token perhaps further secure my cloud server in a similar way. However, before I go that way and destroy what has been an extremely stable environment for years, I want to fully understand it. As the title of this question suggests I am struggling with the concepts.

Here is an ASCII diagram of my plan `O->VPNx` is an outgoing VPN connection to `VPNx->O` server.

```
          (www.chandlerfamily.org.uk)                           (home.chandlerfamily.org.uk) (dev.chandlerfamily.org.uk)
          (mail2.chandlerfamily.org.uk) (Secondary MX)          (mail.chandlerfamily.org.uk) (Primary MX)
       ------------------------------                           ----------------              ---------------
       |    Cloud Server             |                           | ISP Router    | (port fwd) |  Home NAS   |
       |                             |                           |               |O-VPN2----->|     x.x.x.10|
  443->| Nginx 2 Static Web Sites    |                           -----------------            |VPN Server   |
  80 ->| Certbot for Keys            |                  (port fwd)| (port fwd)| |              ---------------
  25 ->| PostFix Mail Open VPN Server|O<-VPN1                     V           | |              
       |       (mail fwd to home)25->|O->VPN2           High Ports|          25 80                 
       -------------------------------                  (for game)|           | |
                                                                  V           V V                                                                
         ------------------------                           (internal PC)   -----------------------------------------------
         |Laptop (443, 587, 993)|O->VPN2                                    | | |                Gateway Machine          |
         ------------------------                                           | |  > Certbot for Keys for internal web sites|
                                                                            | |      DNS and DHCP Server x.x.x.200        |
                                                                     VPN1<-O| > Mail Server      Web Server               |
                                                                        -----------------------------------------------
                                                                                     (all ports open)
                                                                                 Internally home.chandlerfamilly.org.uk
                                                                                 and mail.chandlerfamily.org.uk
                                                                                 appear as x.x.x.200
```

In this setup I install the OpenVPN client on my laptop (and iPhone), on the Cloud Server I install the Debian OpenVPN package.

Here is the bit I don't understand: How does the laptop/iPhone know the address of the SMTP mail server and the IMAPS server? When at home the OpenVPN client will not be running so the laptop and iPhone access the mail (both SMTP and IMAPS) server by the Address "mail.chandlerfamily.org.uk" and the DNS server routes that to IP address x.x.x.200. When out and about "mail.chandlerfamily.org.uk" is the IP address assigned to me by my ISP and although SMTP traffic works, IMAPS would get blocked in my later scenario.

Alternatively I could use the name "imap.home" which in the home also points to x.x.x.200, but when out and about is "imap.home" exposed over the VPN? I think the VPN ".opvn" file effectively tells the OpenVPN client to expose 10.8.0.1 as the tunnel address, but what tells the phone (or laptop) that that is the route to find the subnet x.x.x.0/24 and how does it expose where to go to the DNS?

Similarly for access to the various other services within my LAN, particularly the ability to SSH into different machines, how does the laptop, when out and about, finds them? (This iPhone needs this too - I sometimes receive pictures from Whatsapp which I share with FTPManager Pro to store on the server).

Note: I can see that the `.opvn` file produced by the Synology NAT has two commented out entries (even though I ticked the option to allow clients access to the local network - I have been totally unable to find out what that does) these are the two

- #redirect-gateway def1
- #dhcp-option DNS DNS_IP_ADDRESS

Am I allowed to edit this file to change those (is the certificate effected?) and, if so, are these what I am looking for so both the Laptop and the iPhone always see the internal network?

I suspect the first one isn't what I am looking for. If I browse a random web site on these devices I want to go straight to the internet. But what does the second one expose? Can I see '*.home' addresses?